# US Visa Emergency/Expedite Criteria Meaning

Tags: b1-b2-visas, business-travel, us-visa

I'm applying for a US business visa (B1/B2) and plan to specify an unexpected business emergency to see if an earlier interview date can be given to me so I can travel within the next 2-3 months (in Aug/Sep 2023). Currently, the earliest available interview date is in 2025. Below are the two expedited visa criteria from the embassy that I'm having trouble understanding:

- An unexpected need to travel to the United States for urgent business purposes that is **occurring within 10 days after the first available visa appointment**.
- An unexpected visit that is of significant cultural, political, journalistic, sporting or economic importance that is **occurring within 10 days after the first available visa appointment**.

I do not understand the point in bold about 'within 10 days after the first available visa appointment'. What is this first available appointment that they are referring to, is this the earliest available date in 2025?

Comment: Yes.  Which consulate would you be applying to?  I've seen a couple of instances where a small number of consulates had dates available in the relatively near future, and then, when I checked a few days later, that was no longer the case.  I suspect that they are occasionally adding capacity and then the newly available interview appointments fill up very quickly.  If you check nearby consulates every day you might get lucky.

Comment: They may be referencing appointments for expedited visas which are probably managed separately (but for which they probably don’t provide data).

Comment: @phoog I am applying to the Ottawa consulate. I'll keep checking the nearby ones as well as you suggested, thanks